# Hacer un array de 10 x 10 aleatorio e imprimir el numero mayor y más repetido

Tags: c++, array

He intentado hacerlo (en C++) pero lo sólo me falta la última parte para extraer el mayor y el número que más se repita (si es que se repite).

Soy nuevo en programación y quería saber si hay alguna manera de poder sacar los mayores y repetidos de este código. Que datos se necesitan para completar este código?

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
const int fil= 10;
const int col= 10;
class MATRIZ{
    public:
        Matriz(){
            for(int f= 0; f<fil; f++){
                for(int c= 0; c<col; c++){
                 _Matriz[f][c] =0;
                }
            }
        }
        void Llenar(){
            srand(time(0));
            for(int f= 0; f<fil; f++){
                for(int c= 0; c<col; c++){
                    _Matriz[f][c] =Semilla(200);
                }
            }

        }
        int Semilla(int n){
            return 0 + rand() % (n+1);
        }
        void Mostrar(){
            for(int f= 0; f<fil; f++){
                for(int c= 0; c<col; c++){
                    cout<<_Matriz[f][c]<<" ";
                }cout<<endl;
            }
        }
    private:
        int _Matriz[fil][col];
};
int main(){
    MATRIZ Ma1;
    Ma1.Llenar();
    Ma1.Mostrar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Inténtalo. Para obtener el mayor o menor debes comparar todos los elementos. También puedes usar [`max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element). Para contar las repeticiones de cada número un [diccionario](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) te será útil.

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular el valor mayor de la matriz, iguala el primer valor de la matriz a una variable local

```
int max = _matriz[0][0];
```

luego solo tienes que recorrer la matriz y comprobar si el numero de la variable max es menor que el de la matriz, si es así se lo asignas.

```
if (mayor < _matriz[f][c]) max = _matriz[f][c];
```

Answer (score 0):

Para contar repeticiones en una colección de datos, puedes usar un mapa (`std::map`):

```
int matriz[10][10]
{
     0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
    10,  0, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
    20, 21,  0, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
    30, 31, 32,  0, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
    40, 41, 42, 43,  0, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,
    50, 51, 52, 53, 54,  0, 56, 57, 58, 59,
    60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65,  0, 67, 68, 69,
    70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76,  0, 78, 79,
    80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87,  0, 89,
    90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98,  0,
};
std::map<int, int> valores;

for (const auto &fila : matriz)
{
    for (const auto &valor : fila)
    {
        auto [iterador, insertado] = valores.insert({valor, 0});
        ++iterador->second; // Cuenta cada aparición del número
    }
}
```

Una vez has clasificado todo el contenido, puedes extraer el valor mínimo, máximo y el más repetido así:

```
const auto mas_repetido = std::max_element(valores.begin(), valores.end(),
                [](auto a, auto b)
                {
                    return a.second < b.second;
                });

std::cout
    << "Minimo: " << valores.begin()->first << '\n'
    << "Maximo: " << valores.rbegin()->first << '\n'
    << "Mas repetido " << mas_repetido->first << " un total de " << mas_repetido->second << " veces\n";
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hdLdbtowFAfw6@Qpjpi0gggt@U4I5WbXewKKKpMYZilxkONU1RBPtbvd9r3G/rGhQ@ukXRywj3/HnykPh1lZM7k/nz8JWdZ9xWkp2k4rzpqV@yfXsMNtl9X7Vgn9DcYVUlPDhBxP3KPr2J5W4vvan2@GcB2kHZp7RD4iQISICBEjEkSKyBC5B@kPEuFD@pA@pA/pQ/qQPqRvZAAV@FYHkAFkABlABpABZGBkCBFChoHVIWQIGUKGkCFkaGSE0QgygoxCqyPICDKCjCAjI2OMxJAxZAwZR1bHkDFkDBkbmSCbQCaQCWQCmcRWJ5AJZGJkikwKmUKmkClkCpkmVqeQqZEZehlkBplBZpAZZAaZpVZnRuZo5ZA5ZA6ZQ@aQOWQOmWdGu86pcJ1OV4sFHnuJd/QIPyt6YXWreFe4rrNrFY3LVnaaWK9b@rwTNaPF5cEn9qU/IDMB1IBhDHLM0FporljVqmGpjiuN9oYer0ve2@T4aPoezU@TYqidTq91s1XHsVRV0MMDfem51IxKVjFiB6ZEKd5@SKp4TfLtZ8NVi@ITzomT3OyvYd2z4geuRdVi7csNvD7zmjeYcHzdzJbvh4/ce98dlxW6w4YcZ70Zm8mYZyfdTmz@aP8cxXWvJLF7u19a0vbSLKwYjna5/rLtNZLLJY2@CimadkEjQu@vjcxWO6FwCIzcPcm7awV7/Vih/lPS0fsFmLrbK7mpGVEvSbea1bjUf8nr4Qb6wkvePclR4Z7O51/lrmb77jzDAR/L6TRgvwE)</kbd>.